# Zedgraph GraphPane doesnt has Chart property

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am begining to use ZedGraph and having a strange problem: compiler (C# VS2010) is telling me that "ZedGraph.GraphPane doesn´t contain a definition for Chart...". Code below:

```
        // get a reference to the GraphPane
        GraphPane myPane = zgcAnalise.GraphPane;
        zgcAnalise.GraphPane.PaneFill.Color = Color.Aquamarine;
        myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.Aquamarine);
```

My project has reference to ZedGraph and .DLLs are on project directory.
Can anyone say what stupid thing I am missing, please? 
Thanks...

Comment: Did you add a curve to the graph pane?

Comment: Yes, I did. Four curves. Intellisense just doesn´t show Chart property...

Comment: Did you actually create the object? Your problems sounds like trying to use the properties of an object that does not exist.

Comment: ufff... Various elements of ZedGraph are "missing", like RollingPoitPairList, Scale, etc... Maybe I am working on an old version? Or a bad installation? I downloaded the last version from SourceForge (5.1.5). Can anyone tell what can be happening? Gnqz, I´ll try once more to review my code and pay atention on what you said...

Comment: My suggestion is to download the sample project from the codeproject.com and try to build it. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET) In the link I posted, there are few connections to some old stable versions of the library. I could also provide you with some code I wrote myself (if it would be of any help), but I believe you either miss reference or you something...

Comment: OK Gnqz. Many thanks for your advises. I found the problem. I was using an old version of ZedGraph.dll in release directory of my project. Maybe I installed the old version and after installed the new version; and in this process I have make some mistake in actualization. File changed ==> problem solved. All the wonderfull gifts of Zedgraph was there! Thank you again for your time.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you managed to find the problem :)